# I want to take specific item from this API, how can i do that?

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiFEJ.png)

I want to take a specific and only one value which is "Citta".
You can see the Image for API.

this is my service:

getCitta(){

```
return this.http.get(`${this._host}/Contribuente`, option).pipe(map((res: any) => {
  this._userCF = res.Citta;
  return this._userCF;
}));
```

}

```
  this.userService.getCitta().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this._userCF = data;
    });
```

Comment: `filter` operator?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov I want to take the value of 'Citta', how can i do that because my code above doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` operator in your `pipe`

```
return this.http.get(`${this._host}/Contribuente`, option)
 .pipe(map((res: any) => {
  this._userCF = res.Citta;
  return this._userCF;
}),filter(v=>v);
```

Subscriber will be notified only if `this._userCF` is truthly